# What characters are in whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()?

Tags: cocoa, unicode

I'm parsing some nasty files - you know, mix comma, space and tab delimiters in a *single line*, and then run it through a text editor that word wraps at column 65 with CRLF. Ugh.

As part of my efforts to parse this in Cocoa, I use Apple's `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`. But what, *exactly* is in that set? The documentation says "Unicode General Category Z*, U000A ~ U000D, and U0085". I was able to find the last three (85 is interesting, but what does the ~ mean, and what is General Category Z*?

Any Unicode gurus out there?

Comment: "Any Unicode gurus out there" Be a Unicode guru yourself. Google it.

Comment: Did you actually *try* that before posting? Go ahead and try it now. Googling "unicode General Category Z" turns up page after page of hits which don't define anything, among which there are a few hits back here on SO that don't answer the question either. They are all just definitions, like the one I started with.

Comment: I did try, I found out what a general category was, I found out about the Z categories, I got a list of the characters in them, I ate lunch.

Comment: There's always the choice to loop through through the set and check... leaving no doubts about it.

Comment: @Eiko What a concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSCharacterSet is an opaque class that does not expose its content easily.  You have to see it more as a "membership" rule service than a list of characters.

This may be a somewhat brutal approach, but you can get the list of members in an NSCharacterSet by going through all 16 bit scalar values and checking for membership in the set:

```
 let charSet = NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()
 for i in 0..<65536
 {
    let u:UInt16 = UInt16(i)
    if charSet.characterIsMember(u)
    { print("\(u): \(Character(UnicodeScalar(u)))") }
 }
```

This gives surprising results for non-displayable character sets but it can probably answer your question.

Comment: It does indeed! I then modified the set to include the few items I knew were appearing in my files and I was off to the races.

Answer (score 2):

The ~ means "thru"; thus, U000A, B, C, and D.

The phrase "General Category Z*" is shorthand for "any character whose General Category property is one of the three categories that start with Z." Thus, various forms of space (0020, 00A0, 1680, 2000 thru 200A, 202F, 205F, 3000), plus the line separator (2028) and the paragraph separator (2029).

Comment: Which doesn't actually answer the question. The question is in the context of parsing, and one cannot tell the parser to look for things in "General Category Z".

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. It is a small finite well defined set of characters. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I need to know precisely what those character codes are. Your post does not answer that.

Comment: Okay, I added the character codes. But Stack Overflow is not a "send teh codez" site!